# How to find and replace with special characters using sed?

Tags: macos, sed

I want to replace the ip `'100.45.9.147'` with `$(cat apiServer.txt)`.
A non inplace update works but when i try to use sed's in-place update i get error :-

$ sed "s/'100.45.9.147'/\$(cat apiServer.txt)/g" checkNTP.sh

```
echo -e "\n"
apiServer=$(cat apiServer.txt)
usertoken=$(cat tokenfile.txt)
curl -k  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${usertoken}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://${apiServer}/configapi/v1/SystemSettingsNTP"

echo -e "\n\n"
```

$ sed -i "s/'100.45.9.147'/\$(cat apiServer.txt)/g" checkNTP.sh

```
sed: 1: "checkNTP.sh": command c expects \ followed by text
```

Here is the content of checkNTP.sh

```
echo -e "\n"
apiServer='100.45.9.147'
usertoken=$(cat tokenfile.txt)
curl -k  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${usertoken}" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://${apiServer}/configapi/SystemSettingsNTP"

echo -e "\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below `-i ''` switch solved the case:

`sed -i '' "s/'10.45.9.147'/\\$\\(cat apiServer.txt\\)/g" fileName.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/'\''100\.45\.9\.147'\''/$(cat apiServer.txt)/' file
```

Single quotes are best poked through quoted from the shell, this allows all other characters other than metacharacters to represent themselves and the metacharacters can be quoted as normal e.g. `.` must be quoted `\.` otherwise it just represent a single character.

If you want a shell variable to replace text again poke a hole into the shell and surround the variable  double quotes so as to allow for possible white space. Also remember that should the variable contain metacharacters these should be quoted beforehand otherwise the substitution command might cause a sed syntax error. This usually happens when the variable has characters in it that clash with the substitution delimiters i.e. normally `/`